# Using column function in joins

Tags: sql

In two different tables, I have transactional data containing two different steams of revenue. I also have two tables where the revenue is summarized by month. Now I wish to join the two summarized tables (by month) and have a total revenue number.

```
select  [table1.transaction_datetime:month] as month, 
sum(table1.revenue1) as revenue1, 
sum(CASE WHEN table2.transaction_amount_sign= '-' 
THEN table2.transaction_amount*-1, 
WHEN  table2.transaction_amount_SIGN='+' 
THEN table2.transaction_amount END)*-1 as revenue2

from        table1
full join   table2

on [table1.transaction_datetime:month] = [table2.postdate_and_posttime:month]

where   table1.transaction_type in ('A','B','C')
    table2.transaction_code in ('X', 'Y', 'ZZ')

group by month
order by month desc
```

The results are waaaay higher than what I have with just the individual tables. I suspect I'm not joining the tables appropriately and/or the column functions are screwing the logic.

```
Table1>>
Month             Revenue1
-----             ---------
2019-06-01         $100,000
2019-05-01          $93,000

Table2>>
Month             Revenue2
-----             ---------
2019-06-01          $45,000
2019-05-01          $37,000

Desired Result>>
Month              Revenue1         Revenue2        Total
-----             ---------        ----------     ---------
2019-06-01         $100,000          $45,000       $145,000
2019-05-01          $93,000          $37,000       $130,000
```

Comment: Why `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: could you provide sample data

Comment: Using a full join because I want to include all months (e.g., there may be one type of revenue but not the other in any given month). Add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, you have multiple rows on each day and this is causing a Cartesian product.  Your `full join` also makes no sense, because the `where` clause turns it into an `inner join`.

One method is to use `union all` and `group by` to do what you want:

```
select month, 
       sum(revenue1) as revenue1, 
       sum(signed_transaction_amount) as revenue2
from ((select t1.month, t1.revenue1, null as signed_transaction_amount
       from [table1.transaction_datetime:month] t1
       where t1.transaction_type in ('A', 'B', 'C')
      ) union all
      (select t2.month, null, 
              (case when t2.transaction_sign = '+'
                    then t2.transaction_amount * -1
                    else t2.transaction_amount
               end) as signed_transaction_amount
       from [table2.postdate_and_posttime:month] t2
       where t2transaction_code in ('X', 'Y', 'ZZ')
      )
     ) t
group by month
order by month desc
```